# Ошибка с mysqli_query()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Цель выслать данные в БД
Код :

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123','data2');

$name = filter_var(trim($_POST ['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST ['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_var(trim($_POST ['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$signup = ($_POST ['do_signup']);
function login () {
    global $name;
    global $email;
    global $pass;
    global $mysqli;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$pass')";
    mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);
}
```

Ошибка выглядит вот так Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\Project2\Index.php on line 191

Comment: Как это ? А что мне надо сделать чтобы он видел эту переменную ?

Comment: Да, чтобы он взял переменную из вне функции, но $sql же находиться в функции

Comment: Да, это я ошибся с выводами.

Comment: А я ошибся в вопросе, я исправил

Comment: Погуглите про области видимости переменных.

Comment: Почему надо $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123','data2'); вписать в саму функцию ?

Answer (score 0):

Надо было $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123','data2'); вписать в саму функцию то есть так

```
function login () {
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123','data2');
    global $name , $email , $pass;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `time`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$pass', NOW())";
    mysqli_query ($mysqli, $sql);
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

Comment: Не обязательно. Вы не понимаете как работает функция. Вам надо почитать про `Функции` и `Области видимости переменных`